# Beamer: Show only the frametitle as first slide for each frame

Tags: beamer, pause, frame-title

In my beamer presentation I want when it comes to a new frame to show only the frametitle of this new frame on the first slide for the frame. I know that this is possible by inserting a `\pause` after the `\frametitle`. But maybe there is a global setting which I don't know so far such that I don't have to edit each frame but simply can specify this behavior globally.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Thanks, in the next days I will go through my old questions and do so.

Comment: "Next days" seems to be a very flexible timeframe ...

Answer (score 1):

One remaining problem: first pause has to duplicated

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\only<1>{\pause}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{bla}
    abc
    \pause
    \pause
    def
    \pause
    ghi
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no configuration possible like `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` which deals with the problem?

Comment: I am confused. Is it **title on only the first slide** or **only title on the first slide**?

Comment: @Symbol1 From the description of the questions, I guess your second interpretation? Now if there would have been a MWE ...

Comment: @Symbol1 I meant only title on the first slide. So every slide shows the title but the first one nothing else.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain frame title is a very special space, setting `beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` will probably destroy everything else yet not affect frame title at all.